# iterate through nested array to match IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of data which is nested arrays, these arrays may be empty or they may infact contain an ID, if one of the arrays ID's matches the ID im comparing it with, I want to take all of the data inside that array which matched and assign it to a variable to be used...

example:

```js
data = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"id":"123","name":"DARES HOUSE 2019","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"country":null,"city":null,"type":"Event","members":null}],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

id = 123

matchedArray =
  for (var i = 0; i < potentialEvents.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < potentialEvents[i].length; j++) {

      if (id === potentialEvents[i].id) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
console.log(matchedArray)
```

I'm trying to have it so matchedArray will be the array with thhe matched IDs!!

if you can help, thank you a lot!

Comment: use `Array#filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the inner array and [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method to concatenate filtered array into one.

```js
let data = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"id":"123","name":"DARES HOUSE 2019","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"country":null,"city":null,"type":"Event","members":null}],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];
let id = 123;

let matchedArray = data.flatMap(arr => arr.filter(obj => obj.id == id))
console.log(matchedArray)
```

Comment: oooh `flatMap` not spotted that before. Nice!

Comment: Amazing! I love stackoverflow for this reason, quick, accurate advice, I will make sure I fully understand the methods before I actually use them though. Thank you.

Comment: The matched array returns empty - I don't get an array which has any data

Comment: It was my fault I was comparing an ID that didn't exist that's why. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a combination of `.map`, `.filter` and `.flat`

```js
var data = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"id":"123","name":"DARES HOUSE 2019","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"country":null,"city":null,"type":"Event","members":null}],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

var id = 123;

var matchedArray = data.map( arr => {
   return arr.filter(x => x.id == id);
}).flat();

console.log(matchedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) rather then `.filter`/`.map`/`.flatMap`. The main benefit is that it allows to stop traversing array when element is found.

On big arrays with a lot of data it will be more efficient (≈50 times faster): [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/array-filter-map-flat-vs-flatmap-filter-vs-some-some)

```js
const data = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"id":"123","name":"DARES HOUSE 2019","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"country":null,"city":null,"type":"Event","members":null}],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

const id = 123;
let matchedArray = null;

data.some((a) => {
  return a.some((v) => {
    if (v != null && v.id == id) {
      matchedArray = a;
      return true;
    }
  });
});

console.log(matchedArray);
```